# How to refactor a project which uses both Serialisable and DataContract to use just DataContract

Tags: .net, refactoring, datacontractserializer, datacontract, serializable

I have a project which serialises its data using `DataContractSerializer`. Unfortunately, the persistable classes were not all tagged with `DataContract` - some are tagged with `Serializable` and some with both.

I would like to remove the `Serializable` references and just use `DataContract` for all persistable objects but I'm not sure how to go about this.

How can I retag the classes so that I can deserialise using `Serializable`and then serialise using `DataContract`?

Comment: ctrl+shift+f, "Serializable" ? Although note that you would need *both* of `[Serializable]` and `[DataContract]` if you want to deserialize with `BinaryFormatter` and then serialize with `DataContractSerializer`, but that should work fine

Comment: @Marc - sorry, I am already using DataContractSerialiser - not XmlSerializer as I originally said. So DataContractSerialiser is being used for serialising and deserialising.

Comment: ok; is there something that isn't working? The "problem" is not clear.

Comment: it does work. I noticed that the generated xml contains a lot of nodes which have "strange" names (such as `<_x003C_Address_x003E_k__BackingField z:Id="128">`) and I assumed that came from using `Serializable`. This is why I wanted to to use just one set of serialization tags. Are you saying that it will make no difference?

Comment: ...forgot to say that I want to tidy the xml to make it easier to query using Linq. The BackingField stuff was bothering me.